# Will there be react native for windows phone?

Tags: reactjs, windows-phone, react-native

Since now Android and iOS are both supported. Maybe the next step is to consider on Windows Phone? However, there seems not to have a clear answer on the official site.

Answer (score 12):

Great News :)

Facebook’s React Native gets backing from Microsoft and Samsung. In F8 2016 they have announced the support for Windows 10 Universal App Development.

With this coming in, React Native will be supported on all the major platforms (Android, iOS, Windows 10)

Microsoft has already integrated Windows 10 support on existing React Native [React Native Windows - Github](https://github.com/ReactWindows/react-native)

They have also build an App and planning to showcase the same on coming May 6. [React Native Windows 10 App](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/04/13/react-native-on-the-universal-windows-platform/)

Answer (score 1):

According to Martin Konicek at Reactive 2015, there are no plans to support windows mobile at this time. Refer to the Q&A portion of his talk at 7:06:19 in this recording... https://youtu.be/9cIEtC-V2XE?t=7h6m19s

Comment: There was no plans by their staff, but it is opensource...

Comment: That's true. Microsoft's fork looks very promising and is super exciting. This world is dynamic and ever changing, rendering my answer no longer accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I just read today

> In addition, the company today announced that both Microsoft and
>   Samsung have committed to bringing React Native to Windows 10 and
>   Tizen, respectively. This means developers will soon be able to use
>   React Native to write apps for the Universal Windows Platform (and for
>   the Universal Windows Platform, that may also mean that more
>   developers will now support it, too).

http://techcrunch.com/2016/04/13/facebooks-react-native-open-source-project-gets-backing-from-microsoft-and-samsung/

And here is one more article about it:

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/04/13/react-native-on-the-universal-windows-platform/

So I guess It's coming soon :)